# Difference in function expression

Tags: javascript

Recently I have come across with another way of writing a function expression, like this: `setTimeout(() =>{/*code*/},1000);` as opposed to: `setTimeout(function(){/*code*/},1000);`

What is the benefit of using `() = >` rather than `function(){}`

Can I use it all the time or only in the certain situations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few differences between arrow functions and anonymous function declarations:

- Arrow functions don't have a prototype-property.
- Arrow functions cannot be constructed
- Arrow functions don't bind a this-value, so you'll get the this-instance of the parent scope
- Arrow functions don't have access to the special `arguments`-object

For your use case, it's difficult to say whether it'll make a difference because we can't see the code, but my guess is it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The major benefit is the shorter syntax:

```
var sequence = source.map(t => t.length).filter(s => s > 5);
```

is shorter and more readable than:

```
var sequence = source
    .map(function (t) { return t.length; })
    .filter(function (s) { return s > 5; });
```

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the `this` value

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)